# How to reuse a query in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a query which i want to re use as in in both the methods there is a difference in the way the join is happening.

Query1 :

```
await (from div in Context.ILevelDataItemValue
join pc in Context.Pc
on div.PCIdequals pc.Id
join f in Context.Fund
on div.FundId equals f.Id
join di in Context.ildt
on div.ildtId equals di.Id
join p in Context.vp
on div.PeriodId equals p.Id
**let v = (from v in Context.valwhere v.pcid== pc.Id orderby v.Id select v).DefaultIfEmpty().Last()**
where p.PeriodYear == year && p.PeriodQuarter == quarter
select new TblA
{
pcid = pc.Id,
vid= (int?)v.Id,
fid= f.Id,
PeriodId = p.Id,
ildtid= di.Id,
Value = div.Value                                                                                                 }).ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Query 2:

```
await (from div in Context.ILevelDataItemValue
join pc in Context.Pc
on div.PCIdequals pc.Id
join f in Context.Fund
on div.FundId equals f.Id
join di in Context.ildt
on div.ildtId equals di.Id
join p in Context.vp
on div.PeriodId equals p.Id
**join v in Context.val.Where(val => val.ValuationPeriod.PeriodQuarter == quarter && val.vp.PeriodYear == year).DefaultIfEmpty()
on pc.Id equals v.pcid into val
from v in val.DefaultIfEmpty()**
where p.PeriodYear == year && p.PeriodQuarter == quarter
select new TblA
{
pcid = pc.Id,
vid= (int?)v.Id,
fid= f.Id,
PeriodId = p.Id,
ildtid= di.Id,
Value = div.Value                                                                                                   }).ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Except one joining and other retriving all the values everything remains the same so what is the best way to reuse this query and just replace those join statement with `let v = (from v in Context.valwhere v.pcid== pc.Id orderby v.Id select v).DefaultIfEmpty().Last()`

I have showed the above differences in both the query with ** and ends with **

Comment: Your indenting makes it very hard for folks with phones to help you. The `IQueryable` that the query up to the first `**` represents can be declared once, and then used twice. Try it out; until you materialize the query (with your call to `ToArrayAsync`), the query is just a query

Comment: @Flydog57Sorry for the alignment i have corrected it

Answer (score 1):

You have to divide your query to two projections

First, select everything not related to desired join

```cs
var commonQuery = 
   from div in Context.ILevelDataItemValue
   join pc in Context.Pc on div.PCIdequals pc.Id
   join f in Context.Fund on div.FundId equals f.Id
   join di in Context.ildt on div.ildtId equals di.Id
   join p in Context.vp on div.PeriodId equals p.Id
   where p.PeriodYear == year && p.PeriodQuarter == quarter
   select new TblA
   {
       pcid = pc.Id,
       fid = f.Id,
       PeriodId = p.Id,
       ildtid = di.Id,
       Value = div.Value,                                                  
   }
```

Then you can reuse this query to retrieve additional `id`. Also corrected your queries.

```cs
var firstQuery = 
  from q in commonQuery
  from v in Context.val.Where(v => v.pcid == q.pcid).OrderByDescending(v => v.Id).Take(1)
  select new TblA
  {
      pcid = q.pcid,
      fid = q.fId,
      PeriodId = q.PeriodId,
      ildtid = q.ildtid,
      Value = q.Value,  

      vid = (int?)v.Id                                                
   };

var fsecondQuery = 
  from q in commonQuery
  join v in Context.val.Where(val => val.ValuationPeriod.PeriodQuarter == quarter   
     && val.vp.PeriodYear == year)
  on q.pcid equals v.pcid into val
  from v in val.DefaultIfEmpty()
  select new TblA
  {
      pcid = q.pcid,
      fid = q.fId,
      PeriodId = q.PeriodId,
      ildtid = q.ildtid,
      Value = q.Value,  

      vid = (int?)v.Id                                                
   };
```

Comment: but in this we are unable to reuse select query we are again writing the same code again and again

Comment: Projection is a must, but you can group properties that needs to be copied into one helper class.

Comment: Can we make the commin query as querable and should be executable only when we join both the queries?

Comment: It is already queryable. Execution is triggered only by `ToList`, `ToArray`, etc.

Comment: how do i re use the projection like you mentioned we can copy into helper class.

Comment: You can make projection into helper class `new { data = new {..}}` but at the end you have to make final projection and unwrap properties from helper.

Answer (score 0):

this query is too specific to your context and no one else can easily understand.

but if I read the question correctly, you have a long linq expression, which is very similar to reuse in another scenario, but you need one extra join in the other scenario.

there are at least 2 ways to achieve what you want

1. just write the first part of the expression out, only select the generic fields that can potentially be reused, do not realize the result, i.e. call `ToArray`

you will have an expression that is not executed, and then you can keep adding to the expression. this is called functional composition, nothing is really happening until you realize the results by calling `ToList` or `ToArray` etc.

2. you write a single generic expression that can cover both cases, which takes a predicate as an input parameter. this predicate can act as either include the second join or skip the second join.

not sure if it's clear enough, but here is a quick example

```
    var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
    var threes = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i=> i * 3);
    var fours = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i=>i * 4);
    
    // the first query simply will output a generic results that can be reused 
    var query = from n in numbers
                join b in threes on n equals b
                select (n, b);
    
    // want to join four 
    var query2 = from a in fours 
                join q in query on a equals q.n
                select (a, q.b, q.n);
    
    query2.Dump(); // now this is realizing the results, which will combine both queries
```

be careful though, if you are using sql-to-linq, which may not generate the optimal sql for you. therefore, you want to investigate further and use direct sql instead, something like Dapper may help